# How do you join a table in R with tables in SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, excel, join, merge

I have a quick but tricky question.
What I'm trying to do:

- I have an Excel spreadsheet that I upload in to R studio using
  read_excel()
- I have 2 tables I need to reference from a SQL server db
- I want to only pull date from the SQL tables that match an ID from my
  R table

My issues:

- The tables I'm referencing from SQL are HUGE! I highly doubt I want
  to pull this data into R in order to use it because even if R could
  do this, it would take forever
- I'm struggling with a solution to join cross platform data

Here is an example of some code that shows what I want to do, but I know doesn't work:

```
ExcelData <- read_excel("file_location.xlsx")

HospEnct <- sqlQuery(connClarity, "

  Select H.PAT_ID, H.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID, H.CONTACT_DATE
  From PAT_ENC_HSP AS H
  INNER JOIN ExcelData AS E ON E.CSN = H.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
                     ")
```

I know I could exclude the join and just pull that data into R and work with the dataframe there, but the data I would pull would be too large. I thought I could define the SQL data by date which would work I think, but will still take more time than I'd like to load since there is so much data. Is there a way to do this all in one script, or will I have to pull the data I need from SQL in to R in order to work with the Excel data I pulled in to R? Sidenote: I don't have writing access to the SQL Server, only read, so I can't put the Excel in to SQL and work from there.

Comment: The SQL Query is executed on SQL server. R gives the instructions to SQL as text, asks SQL to run the query, and then R receives the result. To do a join, data needs to be in the same place, either both data sets in SQL or both data sets in R. Perhaps you could create a temp table on your SQL server and put the `ExcelData` in it? Alternately, if `ExcelData` isn't too big, you could use R to programmatically write an `IN` clause instead of the join, something like `paste0("WHERE H.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID IN (", toString(unique(ExcelData$CSN)), ")")`

Comment: Thanks Gregor! Unfortunately I don't having writing access to the SQL sever I'm pulling from, so I wouldn't be able to move my Excel in to SQL to keep everything on the same platform. I could try you IN clause idea. The Excel isn't huge, 160,000 rows, but it will continue to grow as I do this project.

Comment: That's too bad... I'm not sure what SQL Server's limit is for the number of items in an IN clause, but it might not get that big. You could work in batches that way. Or maybe it would help enough to filter on the range of your data? Look at the min and max values in your ExcelData and filter the SQL table to that range before bringing it into R for the join... won't work if your data is widely scattered.